# I'm trying to integrate a folder browser dialog into this batch Mkvmerge Script

Tags: powershell

I want to add a folder browser dialog to this MKVMerge script. I don't know how to take the result of the dialog to specify the script's target directory. Can someone please help me integrate them?

```
#Set MKVMerge.exe Path
$MKVMerge = 'C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe'
#Set Target
$Directory = *this*
$SubExtension = Read-Host 'Input Sub Extension'

#Process
$Subs = Get-ChildItem $Directory -Filter "*.$SubExtension" -Recurse | % { 
$_.FullName } | Sort-Object
$Count = $Subs.count
Write-Host "$Count MKV's to be processed."

Foreach ($Sub in $Subs) {
#Get File Name
$FormatName = $Sub.ToString()
#$Name = $FormatName.TrimEnd(".$SubExtension")
$Name = $FormatName.Substring(0,$FormatName.Length-($SubExtension.Length+1))
$MKV = $Name + '.mkv'

#Set Output File Name
$Output = $Name + '___MERGED' + '.mkv'

#Execute
& $MKVMerge -o "$Output" --default-track "0" --language "0:eng" "$Sub" 
"$MKV"

If (Test-Path $Output) {
      #Clean Up
      Remove-Item $MKV
      Remove-Item $Sub
      Rename-Item $Output -NewName $MKV
  } Else {
      write-host "NON-EXISTENT - $Output" -foreground "red"
      "NON-EXISTENT - $Output" | Out-File $Directory + "Errors.txt" -Append
  }
}
```

Folder dialog Script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
[void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
$FolderBrowser.SelectedPath
```

Comment: Reworded for clarity, fix formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty close (just the beginning of the script):

```
#Set MKVMerge.exe Path
$MKVMerge = 'C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe'
#Set Target
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
[void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()

$Directory = $FolderBrowser.SelectedPath
```

Comment: 'm trying to use a modified folder browser dialog in this same batch Mkvmerge Script. Im pretty sure it's close to being right.                                            https://pastebin.com/whuytAwU